# get Mimetype and encoding charset of text?

Tags: android, character-encoding, webview, mime-types

Hi Everyone,
            I am fetching a text from my DB and before inserting the text into db i know that the encoding of text is ISO-8859-1 , but after fetching from db and before loading this text i am checking the encoding through this code

```
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));
is.getEncoding();   
Log.v("encoding", ""+is.getEncoding());

// String body =  fetched from db
```

and i am getting in the log for the encoding of the text is UTF-8. And this text is not getting loaded on the webview with this method :

```
mailView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, body, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

please suggest me a correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: Refer this link to load webview from string http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingWebViewtoloadstatichtmlstring.htm

Comment: thx for the help but this link was unable to solve my problem , my problem is i want to get charset of a text , and i m getting it when i log the contentType of that text( this text is coming from the mail) as "TEXT/HTML; charset="ISO-8859-1" " .But when i use the code given in the question then log shows it UTF-8.And UTF-8 content must load on the webView and this text is not getting loaded on webview. My problem is how to load this content on the webview ?? provide me a way to get exact encoding information of text and how can i change it to UTF-8 if it is not??

Answer (score 0):

This reply is terribly late, but I stumbled on the question via Google and so thought I'd answer.

As described in the JavaDoc, `new InputStreamReader(InputStream)` will create a reader with the system default (apparently UTF-8). `is.getEncoding()` is simply returning that default which may or may not match your stored data.

In general, it is a good idea to specify the encoding of your stream explicitly. The implication is that you need to store the encoding along with the content. You can use out of band knowledge (e.g., my application only uses ISO-8859-1) but this will be brittle in the event that you change your chosen encoding in the future.

Since the world isn't always a nice place, and strings get separated from their charsets, you might look into a charset detector. See http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection as an example.